# Joining pandas dataframe values on key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to pandas and trying to join dataframe values based on keys.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
Slug  Position   Brand    Session   Transactions   Ecommerce   CTR   Click
A     0          aaa
A     1          bbb
A     2          ccc
A     3          ddd
B     0          bbb
B     1          ccc
B     2          ddd
B     3          eee
C     0          aaa
C     1          ccc
C     2          ddd
A                          70        100             500
A                                                               abc    fgh
B                          60        900             400
B                                                               abd    fgj
C                          50        400             100
C                                                               ab     fp
```

I am trying to make my output to be the following:

Output:

```
Slug  Position   Brand    Session   Transactions   Ecommerce   CTR   Click
A     0          aaa      70        100            500         abc   fgh
A     1          bbb
A     2          ccc
A     3          ddd
B     0          bbb      60        900             400        abd    fgj
B     1          ccc
B     2          ddd
B     3          eee
C     0          aaa      50        400             100         ab     fp
C     1          ccc
C     2          ddd
```

Dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Slug': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
                   'Position': ['0', '1', '2', '3', '0', '1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
                   'Brand': ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
                   'Session': ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',  '70', '', '60', '', '50', ''],
                   'Transaction': ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '80', '', '50', '', '40', ''],
                   'Ecommerce': ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '700', '', '600', '', '500', ''],
                   'CTR': ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'abc', '', 'abd', '', 'ffp'],
                   'Click': ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'ab', '', 'fgh', '', 'fp']})
```

So simply joining the values based on their first key matched.

I am not sure if I should use join or merge because the data is in the same dataframe, not two different ones.

I've tried this

```
df.set_index('Slug').join(df.set_index('Slug'))
```

but get this error:

```
ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['Position', 'Brand', 'Sessions', 'Transactions', 'Ecommerce CR', 'CTR',
       'All clickouts'],
      dtype='object')
```

How would I move on forward trying to get my desired outcome? Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Your data is really hard to copy and to use to create an answer because of all the whitespaces. The best way would be include your data by `pd.DataFrame(..)` so we can copy and run the code.

Comment: Hi @Erfan, I have added the dataframe, hope it helps.

Comment: Well done, upvoted for the effort

Comment: Btw it's not entirely correct yet, have a look at column `CTR` and `click`, the values are wrong there. Can you edit?

Comment: @Erfan, fixed it in the question, thanks for spotting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we use `GroupBy.bfill` to get the values of each group on the first row.

Then get the rows with the lowest `Position` and keep those values and set everything else to `NaN`.

Finally we remove the rows we dont need by filter on `Position not NaN`:

```
df = df.replace('', np.NaN).groupby('Slug').apply(lambda x: x.bfill())

# df['Position'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Position']) --> Use this line if Position column is not numeric
df.loc[:, 'Session':] = (
    df.loc[:, 'Session':].where(df['Position'] == df.groupby('Slug')['Position'].transform('min'))
)

df = df[df['Position'].notna()].replace(np.NaN, '')
```

```
   Slug  Position Brand Session Transaction Ecommerce  CTR Click
0     A       0.0   aaa      70          80       700  abc   fgh
1     A       1.0   bbb                                         
2     A       2.0   ccc                                         
3     A       3.0   ddd                                         
4     B       0.0   aaa      60          50       600  abd   fgj
5     B       1.0   bbb                                         
6     B       2.0   ccc                                         
7     B       3.0   ddd                                         
8     C       1.0   aaa      50          40       500   ab    fp
9     C       2.0   bbb                                         
10    C       3.0   ccc
```

---

**Explanation**:

With `.loc` you can select a slice of your dataframe to enable yourself to alternate that slice. In this case we select `df.loc[ all rows, all columns from 'Session' and onward]`:

```
df.loc[:, 'Session':]

   Session Transaction Ecommerce  CTR Click
0       70          80       700  abc   fgh
1       70          80       700  abc   fgh
2       70          80       700  abc   fgh
3       70          80       700  abc   fgh
4       60          50       600  abd   fgj
5       60          50       600  abd   fgj
6       60          50       600  abd   fgj
7       60          50       600  abd   fgj
8       50          40       500   ab    fp
9       50          40       500   ab    fp
10      50          40       500   ab    fp
11      70          80       700  abc   fgh
12     NaN         NaN       NaN  abc   fgh
13      60          50       600  abd   fgj
14     NaN         NaN       NaN  abd   fgj
15      50          40       500   ab    fp
16     NaN         NaN       NaN   ab    fp
```

`GroupBy.transform('min')` gives us an array back with the same length as our dataframe and on each row the lowest value of `Position` per group of `Slug`:

```
df.groupby('Slug')['Position'].transform('min')

0     0.0
1     0.0
2     0.0
3     0.0
4     0.0
5     0.0
6     0.0
7     0.0
8     1.0
9     1.0
10    1.0
11    0.0
12    0.0
13    0.0
14    0.0
15    1.0
16    1.0
Name: Position, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thas some advanced pandas, will look it into. Could you explain a bit what does `df.loc[:,'Session':]` selects? And what does `.transform(min)` do?

Comment: And I've noticed if I sort the new dataframe by any column descending or ascending it does not work properly, do you have an idea why?

Comment: See edit with explanation. To answer your question about sorting. It's because we use `bfill` and keep only the values of the lowest `Position` per group (reason we used `Groupby.transform(min)`. So if you sort and the lowest Position is not on the first row per group, this method will not work.

Comment: Any workarounds I could somehow get the sorting get working again?

Comment: "Sorting" is quite broad, you have to be more specific (sorting by which column, ascending or descending?). Plus I cannot keep editing this answer and thus see your original question as answered. Feel free to open another question with your additional problems and I would be happy to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant way but should work: make separate DFs for three slices, and inner merge them, then concat with the required empty rows.
UPD: sorry, there was an error with df_dupl, corrected.

```
df1 = df.dropna(subset=['Position'])
df2 = df.dropna(subset=['Session'])
df3 = df.dropna(subset=['CTR'])

# Keep df1 duplicated all but first in each group.
df_dupl = df[df.duplicated('wind speed', keep=False) & ~df.duplicated('wind speed', keep='first')]    

df_res = df1.merge(df2, on=['Slug'], how='inner').merge(df3, on=['Slug'], how='inner')
df_res = pd.concat([df_res, df_dupl]).sort_values(['Slug', 'Position'])
```